# Failed loading of the Jira plugin

Tags: jira-plugin

I'm new to plugin development for Jira. I started with helloworld plugin development process of which is described in Jira documentation. I tried to create a menu with the help of atlas-create-jira-plugin-module command according to the manual and when I tried the project with atlas-run command my plugin failed to load and in the log I found the following:

```
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     ___ FAILED PLUGIN REPORT 

_____________________
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     2 plugins failed to load during JIRA startup.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]           'com.atlassian.tutorial.helloworld' - 'helloworld'  failed to load.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                   Cannot start plugin: com.atlassian.tutorial.helloworld
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                           Unresolved constraint in bundle com.atlassian.tutorial.helloworld [161]: Unable to resolve 161.0: missing requirement [161.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.export)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                   It was loaded from C:\workdir\atlastutorial\helloworld\target\jira\home\plugins\installed-plugins\helloworld-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]           'com.atlassian.tutorial.helloworld-tests' - 'helloworld'  failed to load.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                   Cannot start plugin: com.atlassian.tutorial.helloworld-tests
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                           Unresolved constraint in bundle com.atlassian.tutorial.helloworld-tests [162]: Unable to resolve 162.0: missing requirement [162.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.atlassian.tutorial.helloworld.api) [caused by: Unable to resolve 161.0: missing requirement [161.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.export)]
```

What is the reason of failure?

Answer (score 0):

Read about [spring scanner](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-spring-scanner) (I cannot add comments so I'm writing it as an answer). And if You can please enter Your pom file here. I think that something is missing in Your pom.xml file. And one more thing, did you create plugin with 
**atlas-create-jira-plugin** command?